# Heroku - Express App - Error: spawn compass ENOENT

Tags: heroku, express, compass

I am using the app generated from the official *express* generator, and *CEDAR* stack on *heroku*.

I get the following error when I try to access a stylesheet (`/stylesheets/style.css`)
All the other static assets are loading without problem, and the sass version of the stylesheet (`/stylesheets/style.scss`) also.

*What could be the issue?*

```
2015-03-09T22:27:54.648677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/stylesheets/style.css" host=**.herokuapp.com request_id=c29b6d81-3dae-4e3f-a35a-53f3dea3fb48 fwd="80.244.17.16" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=167ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589437+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:85
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589449+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589447+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589444+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589442+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589446+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn compass ENOENT
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589452+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
2015-03-09T22:27:54.671202+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-03-09T22:27:54.589451+00:00 app[web.1]:     at child_process.js:1137:20
```

Comment: Hello, are you using node-compass middleware ?

Comment: Then this is related to this bug  https://github.com/nathggns/node-compass/issues/34. Compass gem should be installed on your host machine for node-compass to work

Comment: Heroku Support suggested adding this build pack ```https://github.com/stephanmelzer/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt-compass``` but I still get that error.

Comment: I don't know exactly how Heroku works but it seems to me it is pretty hard to fine tune what software is installed. You might consider deploying to a cloud service where you will get more control. I find [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) very easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting I finally got to the bottom of it.

- `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`
- create a file named `.buildpacks` in the root directory and add the following `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git` `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git`
- create a file named `Gemfile` in the root directory and add
  `source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "compass"`
- since heroku can't properly populate the Gemfile.lock you also have to  create a file named `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`
- Push to heroku and node-compass works :)

Comment: Awesome! Can you share where you found all this? This solved my problem. I wonder if its something we can PR into the express generator because its a pain in the ass.

Comment: @JDillon522 I took a lot of searching and this came up by following Error to Error

Comment: @StefanosChrs this works for me too. I was just using SASS with a `"postinstall": "grunt build"` step. I had to switch the order and install ruby first, but everything worked brilliantly. Thanks :)